# Sunrise/sunset photographic opportunities at the Grand Canyon

Tags: photography, vantage-points, grand-canyon

I'm hoping to get a great view of the sunrise at the Grand Canyon.  I'll be staying in Williams, and will be there the first weekend of September.  Where is generally (on the South Rim) considered to a great view of sunrise and / or sunset?  I understand the park is open 24 hours a day at the South Rim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago I stayed the night at [Tusayan](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Tusayan,%20AZ&hl=en&ll=35.997174,-112.111359&spn=0.097495,0.156384&sll=35.993008,-112.110672&sspn=0.0975,0.156384&oq=tusayan&hnear=Tusayan,%20Coconino,%20Arizona&t=h&z=13), about 5-10 miles south of the South Rim of the canyon. There are several standard motel chains and a few restaurants there. I then got up early to drive up to Grand Canyon Village. I can't say if that's the best view, but you can see the photo I captured [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/andrewferrier/4656071728/in/set-72157624174096656) and judge for yourself. I can certainly say that it was an impressive experience in person. It looks like the National Park Service [list sunrise/sunset times](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/sunrise_set_moon.htm).

Comment: That's a great shot! Any chance you have more details on where in the village you went? Or is it fairly obvious upon arrival?

Comment: Mark, it's fairly obvious. There are a few lookout points along West and East Rim Drive. As with most US national parks, it was pretty well organised - they handed me a map on entering the park (Tusayan is just outside the boundaries of the park) with all of that marked on. I can't remember precisely which lookout I was at, but I got the impression they would all be fairly similar. I actually drove up the night before to scope out the place before getting up early for sunrise - the ticket is valid for 7 days' entry anyway.

Comment: I _think_ it was here: http://goo.gl/maps/ryhyT (obviously walking through the trees to the edge of the canyon). But don't quote me on that ;)